# How to forward Google Cloud Load Balancer External IP to Domain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I got my load balancer setup working. My question is how do I get the front-end IP (Internet) redirected to my domain so I don't expose the origin IP?

Answer (score 0):

In the dns settings of your domain set the ip address of your domain to the front end load balancer ip